# Question about using non-binary labels with TFLearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tflearn

I am trying to code a neural network with TFLearn in python 3, and I have a problem related to the labels. The input to the neural network are 1D vectors of length 11. The labels that correspond to these inputs are also 1D vectors of length 11. However, their values are not 0 and 1. Typically in most examples, labels consist of [1,0] or [0,1] as in a case when classifying images of cats and dogs. However, my situation is more unique, and I need to use label vectors that instead look like [4,9,11,2,1,6,4,6,10,1,0]. There are many different label types instead of just 2 as in typical examples, and I can't reencode my labels in terms of vectors consisting of 0's and 1's. My problem is that when use labels in the form shown it doesn't seem to work. Basically, I want to know why this is and how to make TFLearn handle this properly. When I train the neural network I get an accuracy of about 78% typically. However, when I then try the .predict() function it outputs a vector that consists of all values less than 1. For example, it might output [0.3747585,0.0034589,0.06857,0.00384,0.001133,0.04858,0.00045737,0.0068587,0.00100102,0.00066543,0.033322].

The values in my label vectors are always integers between 0 and 11. So I was expecting an output that also had values in this range but instead it outputs values between 0 and 1. How do I fix this? So far I've tried dividing every value in my labels by 11 such that [4,9,11,2,1,6,4,6,10,1,0] would become [4/11,9/11,11/11,2/11,1/11,6/11,4/11,6/11,10/11,1/11,0/11]. However, this doesn't seem to work either. I still get an accuracy result of about 78% and a 0 to 1 output vector, but its behaving like its overfitting. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong programmatically, using the wrong procedure, or if its really overfitting. Below is the TFLearn code that I use.

```
#NN starts
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(input[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(labels[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model
model = tflearn.DNN(net)

# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(input, labels, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)

#Predict
pred = model.predict(testvector)
print('output = ', pred)`
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting output prediction values between **0 to 1** is that you are using **softmax** activation function. [Softmax function](https://medium.com/data-science-bootcamp/understand-the-softmax-function-in-minutes-f3a59641e86d) assigns a probability to each output node in the range of [0,1] that adds up to 1. So you wont get any integer value as your output. Normalization (i.e: dividing by 11) won't work either since each output value is independent of each other.

What you can do is convert your problem into [multiclass-multilabel classification](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/guide-to-multi-label-classification-with-neural-networks/) problem in the following way:

1. For your output label convert each number into binary consisting of four digits (Since maximum value is 11 which requires 4 binary digit). e.g: [4, 9, ...] becomes [0100, 1001, ...]
2. Take each binary digit as a class. So your problem turns into a classification problem. e.g: [0100, 1001, ...] becomes [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...] where every four digit will represent a number of your actual output.
3. This way convert your training and testing dataset label into array of binary digit.
4. Then in your model, instead of using **softmax** activation function you can use **sigmoid** activation function. **Sigmoid** function will assign a probability for each output node in the range of [0,1] (The summation of the probability is not necessarily 1). So, after training your model, your output of prediction should look something like this: [0.0012, 0.7890, 0.0001, 0.0100, 0.8801, 0.0030, 0.0440, 0.9120, ...].
5. Choose an appropriate threshold value to convert your prediction into binary digits. e.g: if we choose 0.5 as the threshold then the output becomes: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...] and then you can consider every four digit as a single number for actual output label.